# Counting and searching for strings

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio

My assignment is already half done, I have made a way to make a word by typing a character into a text box and being able to add it beginning, middle, or end using different buttons. The other half is,
**Character count** counts how many times a specific character appears in the magic word and
displays this number for the user in a label.
**Search** finds if a string exists WITHIN the magic word. If it does exist, it indicates how many
times. It also indicates the characters that appear before and after the found string in the Magic
Word.
**For an 80: Character count works and displays the correct number of times a character appears
in the Magic Word with bugs.
For a 90: Search counts properly but is unable to display the “Before” or “After” Strings.
For a 100: All features work as described and demoed.
For a 110: The program is user-friendly and gives messages to the user about circumstances
including: “String string not found.” It also does not allow the search buttons to be accessed
unless there is both a letter in the appropriate text box and letters in the Magic Word**
[This is what my program looks like so far, the top part's code is already completed but the bottom half isn't and I am currently lost. I will attach all my code so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU8tG.png)

```
Public Class Form1

Dim labelMaxLength = 18

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OriginalText As String
    OriginalText = Label3.Text
    Dim MagicLetter As String
    MagicLetter = TextBox1.Text
    Dim NewText As String
    NewText = OriginalText
    NewText = MagicLetter & NewText
    If NewText.Length() <= labelMaxLength Then
        Label3.Text = NewText
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim OriginalText As String
    OriginalText = Label3.Text
    Dim MagicLetter As String
    MagicLetter = TextBox1.Text
    Dim NewText As String
    NewText = OriginalText
    Dim TextLength As Long
    TextLength = Len(NewText)
    Dim LeftPart As String
    LeftPart = Mid(NewText, 1, CLng(TextLength / 2))
    Dim RightPart As String
    RightPart = Mid(NewText, Len(LeftPart) + 1)
    NewText = LeftPart & MagicLetter & RightPart
    If NewText.Length() <= labelMaxLength Then
        Label3.Text = NewText
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim OriginalText As String
    OriginalText = Label3.Text
    Dim MagicLetter As String
    MagicLetter = TextBox1.Text
    Dim NewText As String
    NewText = OriginalText
    NewText = NewText & MagicLetter
    If NewText.Length() <= labelMaxLength Then
        Label3.Text = NewText
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim OriginalText As String
    OriginalText = Label3.Text
    Dim MagicLetter As String
    MagicLetter = TextBox1.Text
    Dim NewText As String
    NewText = OriginalText
    NewText = Mid(OriginalText, 2)
    If NewText.Length() <= labelMaxLength Then
        Label3.Text = NewText
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim OriginalText As String
    OriginalText = Label3.Text
    Dim MagicLetter As String
    MagicLetter = TextBox1.Text
    Dim NewText As String
    NewText = OriginalText
    NewText = Mid(OriginalText, 1, Len(OriginalText) / 2) & Mid(OriginalText, (Len(OriginalText) / 2) + 2)
    If NewText.Length() <= labelMaxLength Then
        Label3.Text = NewText
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim OriginalText As String
    OriginalText = Label3.Text
    Dim MagicLetter As String
    MagicLetter = TextBox1.Text
    Dim NewText As String
    NewText = OriginalText
    NewText = Mid(OriginalText, 1, OriginalText.Length() - 1)
    If NewText.Length() <= labelMaxLength Then
        Label3.Text = NewText
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Label3.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox2.Enabled Then
        Label4.Visible = False
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Enabled Then
        Label5.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Enabled Then
        Label4.Visible = True
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Enabled Then
        Label5.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks a lot, I am new to coding and will take any advice.

Comment: 1) It would be better if the buttons had meaningful names, e.g. Button7 could be named BtnReset, but apart from that I can't immediately tell which one does what. 2) Instead of two lines `Dim OriginalText As String` `OriginalText = Label3.Text`, you can write `Dim originalText As String = Label3.Text`, and so on, which makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use RadioButton rather than CheckBox to make the choices more user-friendly.
And it can shows the “Before” String of the first “Search” String and the “After” String of the last “Search” String.

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Label4.Visible = False
        Label5.Visible = False
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        Label4.Visible = True
        Label5.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Count_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Count.Click

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Dim count As Integer = 0, ch As Char

        For i = 1 To Len(Label3.Text)
            ch = LCase(Mid(Label3.Text, i, 1))
            If ch.ToString = TextBox2.Text Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
        Label2.Text = "instances:" & count
    End If

    If RadioButton2.Checked Then
        If InStr(Label3.Text, TextBox2.Text) Then
            Dim ct As String() = Split(Label3.Text, TextBox2.Text)
            Label2.Text = "instances:" & ct.Length - 1
            Label4.Text = "First Occurance After:" & ct(0)
            Label5.Text = "First Occurance Before:" & ct(ct.Length - 1)
        Else
            MsgBox("String string not found.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Sorry")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.TextChanged
    If Label3.Text Is "" Then
        Button_Count.Enabled = False
    Else
        Button_Count.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    If TextBox2.Text Is "" Then
        Button_Count.Enabled = False
    Else
        Button_Count.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Result of my test:

[image]

Comment: Wow! this really helped! Thanks so much :DDD !!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to a variable in the same line where it is declared. If you have Option Infer on you don't have to explicitly provide a Type (String, Integer, etc.). The Type in inferred from what you assigned. Hold your cursor over the varaible and you will see its inferred Type.

Set the MaxiLength property of txtLetterToAdd TextBox to 1 at design time. That way the user will only be able to enter a single character.

You have way too may unnecessary variables. If you are using the value out of a control several times in a method, it is wise to create a variable but if it is only used once, just use it directly. Your code is much simpler and easier to read.

When the length of lblNewString.Text reach 18 the buttons are disabled. Since we want to check after each addition we make a separate sub so we don't repeat ourselves.

I am using a Dictionary to keep track of the characters and counts. Each time a new character is added, I check if it is already in the Dictionary. If it is I increment the Value. If no, I add an new entry in the Dictionary with a Value of 1.

```
Private NewStringMaxLength As Integer = 18
Private CharacterCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

Private Sub btnAddBeginning_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddBeginning.Click
    lblNewString.Text = txtLetterToAdd.Text & lblNewString.Text
    DisplayCharacterCounts()
    CheckLengthAndDisable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddMiddle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMiddle.Click
    Dim WordMiddle = lblNewString.Text.Length \ 2
    lblNewString.Text = lblNewString.Text.Insert(WordMiddle, txtLetterToAdd.Text)
    DisplayCharacterCounts()
    CheckLengthAndDisable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddToEnd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddToEnd.Click
    lblNewString.Text &= txtLetterToAdd.Text
    DisplayCharacterCounts()
    CheckLengthAndDisable()
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    lblNewString.Text = ""
    lblDisplayCharacterCount.Text = ""
    CharacterCount.Clear()
    'In case the 18 limit has be reached
    btnAddBeginning.Enabled = True
    btnAddMiddle.Enabled = True
    btnAddToEnd.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayCharacterCounts()
    Dim Letter = txtLetterToAdd.Text
    If CharacterCount.ContainsKey(Letter) Then
        CharacterCount(Letter) += 1
    Else
        CharacterCount.Add(Letter, 1)
    End If
    Dim s = ""
    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In CharacterCount
        s &= $"For character {item.Key} the are {item.Value} occurances" & Environment.NewLine
    Next
    lblDisplayCharacterCount.Text = s
End Sub

Private Sub CheckLengthAndDisable()
    If lblNewString.Text.Length() >= NewStringMaxLength Then
        btnAddBeginning.Enabled = False
        btnAddMiddle.Enabled = False
        btnAddToEnd.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```